# How to applied collect Method from Observable Java to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have the next code in Java:

```
Observable.just("name_one", "name_two", "name_three")
        .collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::add)
        .subscribe()
```

How can applied for Kotlin ?

I tried something like that:

```
source.collect(Callable { hashSetOf<String>() }, { t1: HashSet<String>, t2: String -> t1.add(t2) })
        .map {
            println(it)
        }
        .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor references can be made using `::` before the class name, so the first parameter for `collect` would be `::HashSet`.

For the second parameter, it needs the type specified so it can infer the function's type, so you need `HashSet<String>::add`.

```
Observable.just("name_one", "name_two", "name_three")
        .collect(::HashSet, HashSet<String>::add)
        .subscribe()
```